# React why 'clearTimeout' not work on useeffect return callback

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, react-functional-component, cleartimeout

I have a question about using setTimeout, clearTimeout on React useEffect Hook.

```
    useEffect(() => {
        let timer = setTimeout(() => {
            setRemainingSecond(remainingSecond - 1);
        }, 1000);
        return (() => {
            clearTimeout(timer);
        });
    }, [remainingSecond]);
```

This is my react code with countdown component.
I understand why i should clear timerId everytime the component unmounts due to the memory leak and other sync problem.
But `clearTimeout` is meant to be used to cancel `setTimeout` callback function right?
and since `useEffect` return callback function will be called before component mounts, shouldn't timeout callback function be canceled and nothing happens?

Comment: `and since useeffect return callback function will be called before component mounts` where did this come from?

Comment: *shouldn't timeout callback function be canceled and nothing happens?* I didn't get this part

Comment: If the component re-renders/unmounts _before_ the timer expires, not clearing the set timer will lead to the execution of the callback function of the previous timer which is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

the `useEffect` return callback will run each time the dependency array changes OR the before the component `unmounts` (NOT `mounts`).

In this instance, your timer will continue to go down by 1 every second, but if your component unmounted for some reason, it won't try and call `setRemainingSecond` once the `1000`ms is up, preventing the infamous error:

> Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the undefined component.